# Qt: maximized frame

Tags: c++, qt, window, frame, qt5

I have a beginner question. I'm trying to create a maximized QFrame with the following code but I'm receiving an error which says:

```
error C3867: 'QWidget::showMaximized': function call missing argument list; use '&QWidget::showMaximized' to create a pointer to member
```

Code:

```
 class FrameWindow{

        private:

            QDesktopWidget *desktop;
            QFrame frame_window;
            QRect   frame_rect;

        public:

            FrameWindow(QApplication& app){

                desktop = app.desktop();
                desktop->showMaximized;
                frame_window.setWindowTitle("QT Trainning");
                frame_window.show();            
            }
```

I'm totally beginner in C++, so what I'm missing please?

Comment: functions/methods generally need argument list, even an empty one -> ``object->method()`` Try using brackets.

Comment: eventually you want: ``w->setWindowState(w->windowState() | Qt::WindowFullScreen);``

Comment: Both solutions were helpfull to solve the error, even that the correct answer to my code is (similar) frame_window.setWindowState(desktop->windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized); @SebastianLange - post the code as an answer and I will give you the credits

ps: how can I background as gray my code in comments?

Comment: use ` twice before and after to have a gray background. In Answer areas prepend answers by 4 spaces (or Ctrl+k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functions/methods generally need argument list, even an empty one -> object->method() Try using brackets.

You eventually want:

```
w->setWindowState(w->windowState() | Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Edit:
or as your solution:

```
w->setWindowState(w->windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have already noticed, it's completely counterproductive to pass either the current application or to hold a pointer to the desktop. The application pointer is always available via the global `qApp` macro. To get the desktop, simply use

```
qApp->desktop()
```

There is absolutely no reason to "cache" this value. Get it whenever you need it, that's all.

It'd be also more idiomatic to derive from the widget type, instead of holding it as a member. The code could be simplified as below. It is a complete, self-contained example.

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QApplication>

class FrameWindow : public QFrame {
public:
    FrameWindow(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags * flags = 0) : 
        QFrame(parent, flags) 
    {
        setWindowTitle("Qt Training");
        setWindowState(windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    FrameWindow fw; // constructor is called here
    fw.show();
    return app.exec();
    // FrameWindow::~FrameWindow() destructor is called first before exiting
    // QApplication::~QApplication() destructor is called next
}
```

Comment: To setle the code like this gives me some doubts  like wth is ``parent=0`` and I don't know wth zero. Another thing that drives me crazy is, how you just summon a FrameWindow and make it show without even give a single parameter as a size? One thing that I was realising here and I don't know if its true; if you call ``FrameWindow fw`` inside one method, this will call its constructor? to finish, If you could help me in this other post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141724/how-to-add-a-menu-bar-into-a-window-frame-qt-with-c" I would be very pleasured, thanks!!

Comment: ps: last time I tryed to remove ``desktop = app.desktop();``  that made my entire application crash

Comment: You had other problems. That wasn't one of them :)

Comment: @VictorOliveira: The size is determined automatically by the widget. It will be sufficient to fit the contents, if a layout was set on the widget. Since you set the window state to maximized, it will be shown already maximized.

Comment: Its pretty different to work with C++, Im used with java, which I dont need so many pointers and also declaration and intialization are different things...

Comment: In Java, a variable holding an object is almost exactly like `std::shared_ptr` in C++. So, Java variables are akin to smart pointers, so you *do* deal with them a lot. And in Java you do have constructors just like you do in C++.

Comment: In C++ declaration and initialization are different things too, exactly like in Java. Why? Because you confuse **declaration vs. definition**. In C++, when you define an automatic variable holding an object, you must construct it right then and there, just that you don't use the `new` expression in this case.