# How to add a Menu Bar into a Window Frame? [QT with C++]

Tags: c++, qt, menu, components, addition

I'm a beginner in C++ and I started learning how to use QT components through code at MVS IDE. I still don't know if that was the best option to begin, but since I'm a java programmer, I made the path I made with Java (Swing components). So, my problem is, how to comunicate two class  of my code, since in one I made the window frame and in the other I made my menu bar?

In java I would make something like:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JMenu menu = new JMenu();

frame.add(menu);
```

Anyway, This is my code:

```
#include "Header.h"

class MainWindow{

    private:

        QWidget *widget;

    public:

        void buildWindow(QApplication& app){

            widget = app.desktop();
            QMainWindow *main_window = new QMainWindow();
            QWidget *mainWid = new QWidget(main_window);
            MyMenuBar myMenuBar(mainWid);
            main_window->setWindowState(mainWid->windowState() | Qt::WindowMaximized);
            main_window->setWindowTitle("QT Trainning");
            main_window->show();            
        }

};

class MyMenuBar:QMainWindow {

    public:

    MyMenuBar(QWidget* mainWid){

         QAction *quit = new QAction("&Quit", this);

         QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar(mainWid);
         QMenu *file;

         menu->addMenu(file);
          file = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
            file->addAction(quit);

          connect(quit, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   MainWindow frame;

   frame.buildWindow(app);

   return app.exec();
}
```

I tryed to create an Instance of MenuBar inside the Window class but wans't so helpfull and to be honest most of the materials I found to deal with QT interface they supose that you are using the QT GUI...Any tips about how to solve the problem or what should I really do to practice C++??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify access specifier for inheritance,otherwise default mode is public.

Also, if you are going to have all the classes in the same file the ordering is important(i think). In your case MyMenuBar should come before MainWindow. So, it is a better practice to have different components in different headers and then include them as necessary.

Here is the code for the case where you need two classes separately:

```
class TrainingMenu:public QMainWindow {

public:

        TrainingMenu(QMenuBar *menubar){
            QAction *quit = new QAction("&Quit", menubar);

            QMenu *file;

            file = menubar->addMenu("&File");
            file->addAction(quit);

            connect(quit, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
        }

};

class MainWindows:public QMainWindow{

private:
    TrainingMenu* _menu;
public:
    MainWindows(QMainWindow *parent = 0):QMainWindow(parent) {
        _menu=new TrainingMenu(MainWindows::menuBar()); 
        this->setWindowTitle("Qt training");
        this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
        this->show();
    }

};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   MainWindows window;

   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for the delay to reply, Wanst having time those days to study c++. anyway, the answer was awesome, works like a charm. I realise now that ``*parent`` is the main pointer of the QT application and for every component that I would like to create I need to define it inside the main frame or widget of the application, from there instaciate and pass to its class to handle. Thank you very much brow.

ps: correct me if I understood wrong

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/QMenuBarAddMenu.php#.UkxjBFPIbXQ) example should be good enough. You do the following:

- Create a `QMenu` with the top widget as a parent
- Add submenu `QMenu` instances to the root level menu

Comment: The code is helpfull in a simple way to develop what I want, but doesnt answer the knowledge I want =/ I still can't handle how to do this using two different class.